# O Google indexa imagens com "display: none"

Tags: seo

Como o Google Search usa deep learning em suas buscas, se você buscar, por exemplo, um poema, no google imagens, ele vai pegar uma imagem que contenha o poema (se houver).

Vários sites, como o [Pensador](http://pensador.com), utilizam esse recurso para atrair visitantes. No Pensador.com, a imagem fica visível, **mas a questão é:**  Colocar "display: none" na imagem daria o mesmo efeito? Eu quero que ela apareça na busca no Google Imagens, mas não na minha página renderizada. Pensei em carregar a imagem e setar `display: none` nela.
Há algum problema nisso? Continuará funcionando da mesma forma?

Comment: Acredito que isto pode ser considerado tentativa de fraude e pode ser penalizado.

Comment: Você não deve pensar apenas no Google, deve pensar primeiramente no usuário. Se você acha importante ter uma imagem com poema, coloque dentro da página a possibilidade do usuário poder baixar essa imagem ou visualizar, com isso o Google vai indexar normalmente. Pode deixar um `display:none`, mas crie um botão para visualizar essa imagem ou algo semelhante.

Comment: @Paulo Não tinha pensado nisso. Obrigado.